# Ionic Run Android: Exception in thread "main"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I am building Ionic hybrid application in my company under proxy server. After I run android. It shows Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution because I am working behind of company proxy. I have to configure of my gradle.properties folder in platform/android as following

```
systemProp.http.proxyPort=
systemProp.http.proxyUser=
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.proxyHost=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=
systemProp.https.proxyUser=
```

Comment: Need to create gradle.properties file is not exists. This can also be set globally in the path : c:\Users\<username>\.gradle\